# Why is my day avocado turning brown?

Tags: avocado

I have had this for over a year and they are super temperamental I have learned. It’s happy in its pot but has over the last month started getting these spots. The leaves are soft still not brittle where the brown is. Also have a couple branches that are black but again supple... help. Can’t have it die on me!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVOwE.jpg)

Comment: pictures of the pot size relative to the plant could be helpful to anyone who might hold the answer. I have no experience with avocado trees. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kim! Is it not that the pot does not have good drainage? They can be spots due to excess moisture. Another factor that may be is too much sun exposure.

Comment: Good drainage..and it’s not too big. Killed one with too big pot once...  not sure about sun. We live in sc lots of sun.... but spots didn’t show up until last month...

Comment: I was thinking the pot could be too small. Again, no experience with avocado trees here!